# Raspbian headless ssh (sshswitch.service) file not working

Tags: sshd, raspbian

I just downloaded and wrote the `Raspbian Stretch headless image` to a micro SD card. I added a DHCP configuration to give the ethernet adapter a `10.0.0.254` address. I then gave my desktop PC's ethernet adapter an address of `10.0.0.2` and connected the PC to the raspberry pi with an ethernet cable.

I tested that I am able to ping the raspberry pi on `10.0.0.254` so I know I'm able to communicate with it.

I then followed the instructions in item #3 of the [remote access readme](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/README.md) by placing a single empty file named `ssh` in the root of the boot partition. I mounted this partition on a linux system and verified it contains all the raspbian boot files (such as cmdline.txt).

When I put the SD card back into the pi and boot, the `ssh` file is not removed and I always get a `connection refused` message when attempting to ssh into the pi. Any clue what's going wrong? I used the headless image and this method of access to avoid using a separate monitor and keyboard so the fact that this isn't working is kind of a pain.

Comment: I suspect the HDMI output will still show a login prompt... have you checked? If not, do you have access to the serial interface?

Comment: @Attie I have no doubt that the HDMI output shows a login prompt. I'm trying to access it through ssh though and not plug a monitor into it. Per the readme from the site, you can enable ssh the way I outlined in the post. It's not working as described in their docs

Comment: Well, as it's not working... your best option is to connect to it some other way... or mount the rootfs on another machine and investigate a dead filesystem...

Comment: ... you did make sure that the `ssh` file has no extension, right?

Comment: looking at the [source](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/raspberrypi-sys-mods/blob/master/debian/raspberrypi-sys-mods.sshswitch.service) I'd suggest that it's not being triggered... two options: 1) `/boot` isn't mounted in time / at all, 2) The service isn't enabled.

Comment: @Attie Yes, the ssh file has no extension, but the sshswitch service looks for both `ssh` and `ssh.txt`. The service is enabled and I'm not sure about /boot not being mounted in time but I can try a few things. I would have thought boot would be mounted before systemd starts services but I'll check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by modifying the `sshswitch.service` file to look for the `ssh` file in `/` instead if `/boot`. Then I created the `ssh` file in the root of the `rootfs` partition. Below is the modified `sshswitch.service` which is located at `/lib/systemd/system/sshswitch.service`.

```
 [Unit]
 Description=Turn on SSH if /ssh is present
 ConditionPathExistsGlob=/ssh{,.txt}
 After=regenerate_ssh_host_keys.service

 [Service]
 Type=oneshot
 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "update-rc.d ssh enable && invoke-rc.d ssh start && rm -f /ssh ; rm -f /ssh.txt"

 [Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is what I did to work around my issues, this is not a "fix" for the issue but it might help someone else in the same situation.